# Why is CircuitLab so slow to simulate this simple circuit? (Op Amp DC-coupled to BJT phase splitter.)

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, bjt, circuitlab

Not sure how much is known or published about the back end of CircuitLab, but:

While simulating a different circuit, I noticed very long simulation time.  I narrowed the culprit down to the below portion. With a DC sweep on V1 from 0V to 5V and a relatively large step of 0.1V it still takes several minutes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd1i4b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Changing the Op Amp or BJT model didn't make a difference.

Simply replacing the BJT with a MOSFET speeds up the same simulation so that it runs in a fraction of a second.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJvsZX.png)</sup>

Any ideas what's tripping up CircuitLab?  Is it just that the BJT model implementation is more complex than the MOSFET?

(Please no answers telling me to use different software.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a great idea, but I did notice that if you significantly increase the base resistance of the BJT (change R_B to be at least 10 Mohm) then the simulation is very quick. Seems consistent with the FET being faster. Did you try asking on the Circuitlab help forums?

Comment: What is the need of R3 in the first picture?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I guess it's not needed.  I was tinkering around with it trying to see what might make a difference, and left it in to make sure it was a fair comparison to the MOSFET circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(CircuitLab developer here.) It's much, much faster if you use the Op-Amp model **without voltage rails**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxuWXA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From which I get the following plot in just a few seconds:

[image]

This slowdown is noted in the [CircuitLab documentation](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/circuit-elements/#opamp):

> If the op-amp will not be asked to saturate its output at voltage rails, using the op-amp component that doesn't have the rails will lead to faster simulation, and generally "behaves better" in terms of circuit convergence.

Comment: I can definitely work with this.  The rest of the circuit should be keeping the output far from the rails.

Comment: Why is it so slow compared to Falstad’s? Even using an LM358 with rails? Try this on CL https://tinyurl.com/yjd9ubph or this https://tinyurl.com/yjop4azo